# How to add a floating Action Button inside a scrollview at a specific position in React-Native Expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to show a floating action button at bottom right side of my screen. But as I have one Scrollview component in my Screen I am not getting how should I do that?
In the below  image you can see-

there are some cards in the ScrollView but I want to show  a floating action button at bottom right side of the screen which will overlap the Cards. So, it would be very nice if anyone suggest me with code - How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the action button below your ScrollView code and make it absolute. Here is a working example code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, View, Alert, ListView, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image,ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class Mynewproject extends Component {


 SampleFunction=()=>{

  // Write your own code here, Which you want to execute on Floating Button Click Event.
  Alert.alert("Floating Button Clicked");

}

render() {

return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

       <ScrollView>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>

       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>

       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>

       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>

       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>
       <Text>sdds</Text>

       <Text>sdds</Text>

       </ScrollView>

        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={this.SampleFunction} style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle} >

          <Image source={{uri : 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Floating_Button.png'}} 

          style={styles.FloatingButtonStyle} />

        </TouchableOpacity>

</View>

   );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 MainContainer :{

   justifyContent: 'center',
   flex:1,
   margin: 10
 },



 TouchableOpacityStyle:{

     position: 'absolute',
     width: 50,
     height: 50,
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'center',
     right: 30,
     bottom: 30,
   },

   FloatingButtonStyle: {

     resizeMode: 'contain',
     width: 50,
     height: 50,
   }
});
```

Comment: Works very well. Note to future self: it doesn't work when you try putting it inside a PagerView. For that, you can put the FAB in the parent component, besides, Android also doesn't recommend putting FABs inside tabs (AFAIK).

Comment: why does MainContainer.flex=1 make the difference whether the scollview can scroll or not? I read that it determines the fill of each component (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox), so why would it make a difference to the scrollbar of the scrollview?

Answer (score -4):

The View should be outside the `ScrollView` and the position in style properties should be `fixed`. The bottom and right properties show the space between view and the screen ends

```
<ScrollView>
...
</ScrollView>
<View style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 10, right: 10, zIndex: 200 }}>
    <Icon name="plus" size={25} color="#8E8E93" />
</View>
```

Comment: There is no such position as fixed in React Native

Comment: As @Ajay mentioned, this is not applicable in react-native