# I want to implement a submit button just like this with a transparent background but since I'm new to RN, I can't quite figure it out

Tags: react-native, user-interface, touchableopacity

It isn't turning out how I want it to be
[Figma Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQO5C.png)  and the
[Coded in React Native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YemZH.png)

I want it to float and have a transparent background while being stuck to the bottom of the screen like I have shown in the Figma design.

```js
const TicketDetails = () => {
  return (
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#D0DEEA', flex:1, position: 'relative'}}>
    <ScrollView style={styles.containerMain} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      <View style={styles.topNavigation}>
        <Back/>
        <Close/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
        <Text  style={styles.heading}>Create New Ticket</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
          <Text style={styles.formHeading}>Enter Ticket Details</Text>
          <Filter/>
        </View>
        <CustomDropdown data={serviceType} text={'Service Type'} placeholderText={'Select Service Type'}/>
        <CustomInput2 heading={'Assign Dealer'} placeholder={''}/>
        <CustomInput2 heading={'HMR'} placeholder={'Enter HMR Value'}/>
        <CustomDropdown data={criticality} text={'Criticality'} placeholderText={'Select Criticality'}/>
        <CustomDropdown text={'Customer Concerns'} placeholderText={'Select..'}/>
        <CustomInput2 heading={'Expected Date'} placeholder={'31 Dec 2022'}/>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.nextButton}>
      <Submit text='Next' style={{position:'absolute'}}/>
    </View> 
  </View>
  )
}
```

```css
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerMain:{
    marginTop:60,
    backgroundColor:'#D0DEEA',
    opacity:1,
    position:'relative'
  },

  formContainer:{
    flex:0.7,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 35,
    marginTop:40,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.4,
  },

  nextButton:{
    flexDirection: 'column', 
    flexGrow: 1,            
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },

  topNavigation:{
    marginLeft:13,
    marginRight:13,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }

})
```

It's either there at the scroll end or does not appear to be floating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example for you:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image,View, ScrollView, 
Text,TouchableOpacity } from 'react- 
native';

const logo = {
  uri: 

'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
  width: 64,
  height: 64
    };

const App = () => (
<View>
<ScrollView>
<Text style={{ fontSize: 96 }}>Scroll me 
plz</Text>
<Image source={logo} />
<Image source={logo} />
<Image source={logo} />
<Image source={logo} />
<Image source={logo} />

<Image source={logo} />
<Image source={logo} />
<Image source={logo} />
<Image source={logo} />
<Image source={logo} />
<Text style={{ fontSize: 96 }}>Scrolling 
 down</Text><Image source={logo} />
<Text style={{ fontSize: 96 }}>What's the 
best</Text>

<Text style={{ fontSize: 96 }}>Framework 
around?</Text>

<Text style={{ fontSize: 80 }}>React 
Native</Text>
</ScrollView>
<TouchableOpacity style={{
position: 'absolute',
width: '90%',
height: 50,
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 bottom: 30,
 left:15,
 right:5,
 backgroundColor:'#ff00ff',
 borderRadius:20
}} >

  <Text >text</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This request is a basic CSS knowledge.
Add **position: 'relative'** to the styles of the area that should snap under.
Add **position: 'absolute'** to your button styles. And your wish will come true.
If that doesn't help please share your sample code.

```
// this card component
<View style={{position: 'relative'}}>

    // this button component
    <TouchableOpacity style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0}}>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

</View>
```

Comment: It's actually inside a scroll view so I also want it to be locked while scrolling

Answer (score 0):

```
const TicketDetails = () => {
return (
<View style={{backgroundColor:'#D0DEEA', flex:1, position: 'relative'}}>
<ScrollView style={styles.containerMain} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
  <View style={styles.topNavigation}>
    <Back/>
    <Close/>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.headingContainer}>
    <Text  style={styles.heading}>Create New Ticket</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.formContainer}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <Text style={styles.formHeading}>Enter Ticket Details</Text>
      <Filter/>
    </View>
    <CustomDropdown data={serviceType} text={'Service Type'} placeholderText={'Select Service Type'}/>
    <CustomInput2 heading={'Assign Dealer'} placeholder={''}/>
    <CustomInput2 heading={'HMR'} placeholder={'Enter HMR Value'}/>
    <CustomDropdown data={criticality} text={'Criticality'} placeholderText={'Select Criticality'}/>
    <CustomDropdown text={'Customer Concerns'} placeholderText={'Select..'}/>
    <CustomInput2 heading={'Expected Date'} placeholder={'31 Dec 2022'}/>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
  <TouchableOpacity style={{
position: 'absolute',
 width: '90%',
 height: 50,
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 bottom: 30,
 left:15,
 right:5,
 backgroundColor:'#ff00ff',
 borderRadius:20
}} >

  <Text >text</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>


  </View>
 )
   }
```

Comment: It's actually inside a scroll view so I also want it to be locked while scrolling

Comment: move your touchableopacity outside of scrollview...

Comment: but then it won't look like it is looking in the figma design

Comment: you can define commponent everywhere ... just outside of scrollview tag..

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Adding in code to the question, please refer

Comment: i also created button like this

Comment: your code not appear.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/embedded/@aboutreact/floating-action-button-example?preview=true&platform=ios&iframeId=e60lxa8p04&theme=dark

Comment: like answered code in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655754/how-to-add-a-floating-action-button-inside-a-scrollview-at-a-specific-position-i

Comment: did you succeeded?

Comment: uploaded the code for reference

Comment: test my answer now

Comment: did not work. It does not appear floating above the form.